# What is the most basic way of referencing JS/CSS files in a Django Application?

Tags: javascript, css, django

So I have just begun learning the Django framework, and I am trying to make a basic application using AJAX to load Django responses into my main 'Content' div. So far so good, but one issue I am having is referencing JS/CSS files. All I want is a link to one CSS file, and one JS file in my main index page.

What I am hoping to do is add a reference to `style/main.css` and `js/main.js` in my application's `urls.py` script, where python would return the contents of the file. So, a standard `<link src='style/main.css' ... />` tag would receive the contents of the appropriate file.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically compute some values for the CSS/JS files or just to serve them off the disk?

Comment: Just simply serve them off the disk, I just cannot find the proper way to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation on serving static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/). Essentially, you can use Django to serve these files during development, but should definitely configure your web server (e.g. Apache) to serve them directly in your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Setup "django.contrib.staticfiles" properly.

Add your link and script tags to your template using your STATIC_URL setting.

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/main.css"/>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/main.js"></script>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

1. open your settings.py and

   -add this at the first line of your file:

   import os.path

   -change your STATIC_ROOT's value to:

   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/')

   -change your STATIC_URL's value to:

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
2. create a folder named "static" in your project root.
3. create a folder for your static files like css, javascript and etc. I recommend you use a different folder for different types of files.
4. open the urls.py of your project
   -add this to your imports: import settings
   -add this to the url patterns:

   (r'(?:.*?/)?(?P(css|jquery|jscripts|images)/.+)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT }),

   NOTE: In this example, there are folders named css, jquery, jscripts and images inside my static folder.
5. In your template add this:

for css files: (in this example, default.css is the name of the css file)

```
<link href="/{{ STATIC_ROOT }}css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

for javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/{{ STATIC_ROOT }}jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```